# React Native Navigation (ver4.x) unable to get props in custom header component. Keep getting undefined error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I have a custom header in my app and I am trying to get the navigation to open the Drawer when clicked on the menu item in the header component. I've passed the navigation and the header text as props to the component. However the props are being returned as undefined.

This is my header

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, Text, Image, Alert, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Colors from '../constants/Colors';
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';


const Header = ({navigation, headerText}) => {

 
    const openMenu = () => {
        console.log({headerText}) **/// this prints Object {  "headerText": undefined,}**
      navigation.openDrawer() **/// this also throws an undefined error**
    }

    console.log(headerText)**/// this displays the headerText correct on loading**

    return (
        <View style={styles.header} >
            <MaterialIcons onPress={openMenu} name='menu' size={30} style={styles.icon} />
            <Text style={styles.logo}>My Home Page Header</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    header: {
        paddingTop: 20,
        width: '100%',
        height: '10%',
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    logo: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '90%',
        fontFamily: 'pacifico-regular', 
        fontSize: 28,
        paddingTop: 20,
        paddingLeft: 20,
    },
    icon: {
        marginTop:30,
        paddingLeft: 10,
    },
});

export default Header;
```

console.log(headerText)/// this displays the header text correctly when loading the component.
However trying to use the props in the Text or the View throws an undefined error.

Clicking on the MaterialIcon menu icon gives the error :
**Object {
"headerText": undefined,
}**

and
**TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.openDrawer')**

This is the homestack.js

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import NewFeaturedRecipes from '../screens/NewFeaturedRecipes';
import NewRecipeDetails from '../screens/NewRecipeDetails';
import Header from '../shared/Header';
import React from 'react';
import {navigation} from 'react-navigation'

// const navigation = navigation;

const screens  = {
    NewFeaturedRecipes: {
        screen: NewFeaturedRecipes,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
            return {
                headerTitle: () => <Header navigation={navigation}
                  headerText='Testting headertext from hoomestack' />
            }
        }
    },
    NewRecipeDetails: {
        screen: NewRecipeDetails,
        navigationOptions:  {
            title: 'Recipe Details',
        }
    },
}

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(screens, {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
        headerStyle: {
            height: 20,
        },
    }
});

export default (HomeStack);
```

Comment: Try this way `headerTitle: (props) => <Header {...props} navigation={navigation} headerText='Testting headertext from hoomestack' />`

Comment: @dianaqqq tried this but still the same errors

Comment: And before returning the headerTitle, if you console.log the navigation, it isn't undefined? Also, in general when I had something like this, I added an `onPress` prop to my headerTitle and I handled the `onPress` right where I have the stacks. `<Header onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()} headerText='Testting headertext from hoomestack' />`. However, if you want to handle the things the way you did, you could define your props interface inside the `headerTitle` like this `export interface Props extends NavigationScreenProps{ ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the answer if anybody is interested. I've used React Navigation 5.x for the nested navigators and I am able to call the openDrawer() from the menu in the Header component.

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, DrawerLayoutAndroid } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {createDrawerNavigator} from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';


const Header = ({ headerText }) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation()
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
      <MaterialIcons onPress={()=> navigation.openDrawer()} name='menu' size={30} style={styles.icon} />
      <Text>Header Text = {headerText}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')} title='Goto Details Screen' />
    </View>
  )
}

const DetailScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Detail Screen</Text>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')} title='Goto Home Screen' />
    </View>
  )
}

const HomeStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name='Home'
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          headerTitle: props => <Header headerText='Text from App' />
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen name='Details' component={DetailScreen} options={{
          headerTitle: props => <Header headerText='Text from Details' />
        }}
        />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

function NotificationsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', flexDirection:'column' }}>
      <Text>Notifications Screen</Text>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} title="Go back home" />
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator()
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator()

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName='Home'>
        <Drawer.Screen name='Home' component={HomeStack}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name='Notifications' component={NotificationsScreen}/>
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

export default App

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```